# Fresh CentOS install with Apache in VirtualBox: Host OS can't access the test page

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, virtualbox

Context: I just got a job as a sysadmin and my employers are quite aware that I'm new to this scene so they're having someone show me the ropes. Her first task for me was to set up a VM with CentOS.

I've set up CentOS on my VM and I installed Apache without incident. When I tried to access it using the browser on the host via IP address, it says that it took too long to respond (using Google Chrome).

I've set network adapter of the VM to a bridged adapter and I'm not using the loopback address for this. I tried using

```
curl myipaddress
```

And it shows the HTML just fine. I tried pinging the VM's ip address and it replies fine.

I tried ruling out iptables. What I got when I tried to stop it:

```
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.
```

Which upon further checking implies that iptables isn't installed.

I tried checking the status of the service with

```
sudo service httpd status
```

And it's apparently working fine.

I basically left the settings at their default so I'm not sure what I'm overlooking. It looks like a misconfiguration but I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: Which CentOS release how did you install apache. what does `iptables-save` tell you. Are you running SElinux(Security Enhanced Linux)?. Check it using `sestatus`.  What is the `DocumentRoot` of your server.

Comment: CentOS 7. I installed apache through

Comment: CentOS 7.x doesn't use `iptables` anymore, it uses `firewalld` instead.  Also `selinux` is enabled by default. Can you provide more details about your environment?

Comment: CentOS 7. I installed apache through 'yum install httpd'. 'DocumentRoot' is set at '"var/www/html"' which I think is the default. I'm hosting this on VirtualBox with Windows 7 as the host OS. For most part, I left it at the default settings.

Comment: If `curl` works and your browser doesn't, check your browser's proxy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to open the ports through firewalld (the default firewall in Centos 7).

You can try, just for testing:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
```

To see what active zones you have, you can use:

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

And then, a port (i.e. tcp 80 for http) can be opened, let's say for the zone 'public':

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
```

The reload firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

The option permanent makes the rule permanent, even if the service or server restarts. You will need to run the commands as root or use sudo.

Comment: Gave it a try. Works like a charm.